# GCC 4.8.1 compile time in C99 code with many macros and inline functions

Tags: c, gcc, macros, inline, c99

I try to compile a code with many lines of Algebra in it. Basically, it is a brute force contraction of 2 tensors with 12 dimensions and variable mode size. However, the performance of the code is not an issue at the moment, since it does not even compile. The code itself is embedded in a larger framework written in C99, which tries to mimic C++ behaviour, i.e. it uses macros for substituting templates and many inline functions. Basically, this is what does not compile (I know it is not elegant, but the code is generated using Mathematica in order to get the tensor indices right. It will be optimized later on):

```
void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) MP(dineutron_uddu)(double complex* result, double complex* VVV_, double complex* vMv_, unsigned int L, int tis){

    unsigned int lt=(unsigned int)nsites_dir[TUP];
    double complex (*vMv)[L][4][lt][L][4]= (double complex (*)[L][4][lt][L][4]) vMv_;
    double complex (*vvv)[L][nt][L]= (double complex (*)[L][nt][L]) VVV_;
    unsigned int nnodes3=nnodes_dir[XUP]*nnodes_dir[YUP]*nnodes_dir[ZUP];
    unsigned int mynode3=mynode_dir[XUP]+nnodes_dir[XUP]*(mynode_dir[YUP]+nnodes_dir[YUP]*mynode_dir[ZUP]);

    {
            unsigned int tf;
            for(tf=0; tf<lt; tf++){
                    int tfs= lt*mynode_dir[TUP]+tf;

                    unsigned int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11;
                    COMPLEX sum=0.;
                    unsigned int run=0;

                    for(n0=0; n0<L; n0++){
                            for(n1=0; n1<L; n1++){
                                    for(n2=0; n2<L; n2++){
                                            for(n3=0; n3<L; n3++){
                                                    for(n4=0; n4<L; n4++){
                                                            for(n5=0; n5<L; n5++){
                                                                    for(n6=0; n6<L; n6++){
                                                                            for(n7=0; n7<L; n7++){
                                                                                    for(n8=0; n8<L; n8++){
                                                                                            for(n9=0; n9<L; n9++){
                                                                                                    for(n10=0; n10<L; n10++){
                                                                                                            for(n11=0; n11<L; n11++){

                                                                                                                    if(run%nnodes3==mynode3){

                                                                                                                            sum += vvv[n0][n4][tfs][n8] * vvv[n1][n5][tfs][n9] * ~(vvv[n2][n6][tis][n10]) * ~(vvv[n3][n7][tis][n11]) * 

    (

     + 0.25 * vMv[0][n2][0][tf][n9][1] * vMv[0][n3][0][tf][n5][1] * vMv[0][n11][0][tf][n4][1] * vMv[0][n7][1][tf][n8][0] * vMv[0][n10][1][tf][n1][0] * vMv[0][n6][1][tf][n0][0]
```

.....

about 600 lines of code follow, wich are pretty much like the previous one, but for different combinations of indices. It cannot be simplified further algebraically.
....

then the loops close and that is it.

So basically, the code just contains complex additions and multiplications, using the C99 double complex datatype. The loop indices are not known at compile time.
I specified the attribute O0 in order to turn of optimizations to check whether this causes trouble, but it still just hangs. 
My question is:

1) does any of you know what is going wrong here?
2) if not, how can I find out, i.e. print the actual line of code the compiler is working on, i.e. getting some kind of live-output of what the compiler does.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried comparing with a different compiler like clang or the Intel C compiler?

Comment: That gives me (icc): 
space exceeded in Data Dependence Test in dineutron_udduf
Subdivide routine into smaller ones to avoid optimization loss

Comment: However, it seems to compile though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you split your function into several pieces and put each mini function into a separate file (translation unit)?  I imagine GCC takes an exponentially long time in rearranging [basic blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block)
2. Perhaps you can play with `-fdump-`... optionis?

   - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Comment: Yes, this works. I did not split it up actually but rather commented out many lines of the code. Is there an easy way to tell gcc not trying to rearrange the blocks? The more lines of code i include the longer it takes. The compile time seems to grow combinatorially (as does the number of possible block reorders).

Comment: I'm afraid but basic blocks are so elementary and fundamental concept in the compiler internal logic that we cannot directly control or interfere how they are handled.  Splitting your function into several files is the only way I know.  Can you copy&paste your actual code to http://pastebin.com/ so that I can see the structure of 600+ lines of code?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I used mathematica on that to factor out terms and that is still possible, but translating the resulting expression into program code is not done yet, but I will work on that. At the moment, I can only do flat expressions wich are fully expanded.

Comment: Hmm, GCC provides options specifically about rearranging basic blocks, so please try `-fno-reorder-blocks` and `-fno-reorder-functions` first http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html  But they shouln't be turned for `-O0`

Comment: Hmm. It works with the intel compiler (see above), but he complains that the optimization might not be optimal :)
(I cannot use pastebin at the moment, it complains that it is under too heavy load).